# pandas to_datetime is rendering some dates as 'floating' dates

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

pandas is reading hourly data from 2017-2019 from an excel file. I use the function to_datetime on the index which are dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

```
train = pd.read_excel(path,index_col=0)

train.index = pd.to_datetime(train.index)
```

When checking for missing dates I do the following:

```
start_date = train.index[0]
end_date = train.index[len(train)-1] 
dti = pd.date_range(start=start_date,end=end_date, freq='H')
print(train.index.difference(dti))
```

Which is something I do regularly and has not resulted in problems previously.

What I get this time is strange, in lack of better wording it seems that some of the dates in the train dataset are rendered as floating timestamps.

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-06-09 01:59:59.990000', '2017-06-09 02:59:59.985000',
               '2017-06-09 03:59:59.980000', '2017-06-09 04:59:59.975000',
               '2017-06-09 05:59:59.970000', '2017-06-09 06:59:59.965000',
               '2017-06-09 07:59:59.960000', '2017-06-09 08:59:59.955000',
               '2017-06-09 09:59:59.950000', '2017-06-09 10:59:59.945000',
               ...
               '2019-07-31 13:59:59.930000', '2019-07-31 14:59:59.925000',
               '2019-07-31 15:59:59.920000', '2019-07-31 16:59:59.915000',
               '2019-07-31 17:59:59.910000', '2019-07-31 18:59:59.905000',
               '2019-07-31 19:59:59.900000', '2019-07-31 20:59:59.895000',
               '2019-07-31 21:59:59.890000', '2019-07-31 22:59:59.885000'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=200, freq=None)
```

I have inspected the dates resulting in floating timestamps in the excel file and cannot find anything out of the ordinary (no missing dates as I can tell).

Anyone know why this strange problem can occur or just a way around it. Its worth mentioning that I know there are 12 extra timestamps in the training dataset than in the daterange just by looking at the lengths, and I would rather not just create a new daterange for the index before I know the reason for the extra timestamps.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example for further analysis?

Comment: @mozway sadly I'm using a private dataset, so if the problem lies there I cant share it. If it helps, I realized that there were missing values in some of the other columns on the affected dates. So there might have been some issues in the compilation of the excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would bet for a one-off error, you're probably having one day extra and this is spread over the whole values.

You can `round` the values to get rid of the milliseconds:

```
dti = pd.date_range(start=start_date,end=end_date, freq='H').round('S')
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! Didn't know you could round datetimes, had to do it on the train.index datetime though.